# Hotmail adding p tags within email, creating unwanted spacing

Tags: html, email, outlook

I've created an email signature, using tables for layout as I've [read](http://www.webdevdoor.com/html-css/html-email-development-tips/) this is the best approach. Everything looks great for internal emails sent via Outlook 2013 but annoyingly when viewing an email in Hotmail, a bunch of spacing has been injected per `<tr>`. Viewing the source reveals that the content within the `<tr>` is being wrapped in a `<p>` with a .ecxMsoNormal class specified.

The `p` tag is being set a bottom-margin of 1.35em, hence the spacing issue. I've tried to override the class but it looks like `<style>` tags are being stripped before Outlook 2013 sends the email or it's completely getting ignored server side.

Is there a way to remove this spacing? If not, what would be a suitable work around? Nothing I try (table layout, div layout, wrapping inner content in font/div tags, overriding styles) seems to get rids of these `p` tags.

Edit:

See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK0nE.jpg) for more details.

Comment: Are you sure it is the `<tr>` and not `<table>` tags? This big a gap is usually due to the tables getting wrapped in `.MsoNormal`, while rows usually only have a couple of pixels vertical gap at most.

Comment: I've added an image which should better help illustrate the issue.

Comment: have you tried using font tags instead of spans?

Comment: @John I have and still get `<p>` tags inserted.

Comment: same problem, driving me nuts....

Comment: Based on the advice from a Microsoft moderator on the Microsoft Community website (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/how-to-overide-pmargin-0-0-135em-0-in-outlookcom/e170983e-7f6f-4c11-96f6-c5f7aa546c56), I submitted a feedback request to allow overriding the default <p> margins in outlook.com.

Comment: is there an update to this. i am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You should never use <kbd>p</kbd> tags when coding an HTML email because various email clients add their own style to paragraphs which can not be completely predicted or overwritten.

Instead, you should use <kbd>span</kbd>.  To achieve a paragraph effect you can write a double break after each  block.

An example of two paragraphs would be:

```
<span>Paragraph</span>
<br><br>
<span>Paragraph</span>
```

Comment: no <p> tags were used. They are automatically inserted by Outlook when the email is being sent out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where we had no option but to use p tags, and wanted to remove the 1.35em margin-bottom.

I used `display:inline;` on the p tags in question so that the margin was ignored. Not appropriate in all situations, but was perfect for us.

Comment: It seems that all styles are stripped from <p> tags and made styling them virtually impossible