# sending html signature from outlook does not render well in hotmail

Tags: outlook, html-email, hotmail

I have a html sig which i want to send from outlook. it renders fine but the problem is **hotmail** displays it differently.

It adds extra p tags with padding. class called `ecxMsoNormal`

Below is html of what i am trying to send from MS Outlook 2010 to hotamil.com. it renders well in most clients but not in hotmail.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
p.MsoNormal {
    margin: 0px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

p.ecxMsoNormal {
    margin: 0px !important;
}

td {
    padding: 0px !important;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <table style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; min-width: 400px;max-width:525px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="100%" style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
                    <td>
                        <table style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
                        <tr>
                                <td valign="bottom" nowrap style=" line-height:1px; border-top: 1pt solid black; ">&nbsp; </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="bottom" nowrap style="  "><SPAN
                                    STYLE="color: #005a83; font-size: 11pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Shamraiz Akhtar</SPAN></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="bottom" align="left" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:23px; height:23px;" nowrap><SPAN
                                    STYLE="color: #92d050; font-size: 10pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;  vertical-align: bottom ; ">Technical Support Engineer</SPAN></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td valign="bottom">
                    <table width = "100%"><tr>
                    <td valign="bottom" ><img width="168.2" height="46.5" align="right" src="https://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg" nosend="1" /></td>
                    </tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style=" width: 100%; line-height:23px; height:53px;" >
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" nowrap><SPAN STYLE="color: #92d050; font-size: 9pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&nbsp; t:</SPAN>
                        <span
                            STYLE="color: #005a83; font-size: 9pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;">+44 1483 730201</span></td>
                            <td></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="center" style='padding-left: 10px;' nowrap><SPAN STYLE="font-size: 14pt; margin: 0; padding: 0;">| </SPAN></td>
                        <td></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="center" style='padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in' nowrap><SPAN STYLE="color: #92d050; font-size: 9pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;">f:</SPAN>
                        <span STYLE="color: #005a83; font-size: 9pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;">+44 1483 762620</span></td>
                        <td></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="center" style='padding-left: 10px;' ><SPAN STYLE="font-size: 14pt; margin: 0; padding: 0;">| </SPAN></td>
                        <td></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right" style='padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in' nowrap><SPAN STYLE="color: #92d050; font-size: 9pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;">w:</SPAN>
                        <span STYLE="color: #005a83; font-size: 9pt; font-family: arial; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                        <a STYLE="color: #005a83; text-decoration: none !important;" href="www.spectrumgeo.com">spectrumgeo.com</a></span></td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; line-height:23px; height:53px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="9" style='padding: 0in 0in 0in 0in'><SPAN
                            STYLE="color: #005a83; font-size: 8pt; font-family: arial;">&nbsp; Dukes
                                Court, Dukes Street, Woking, Surrey, GU21 5BH, UK</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><SPAN STYLE="color: #005a83; font-size: 8pt; font-family: arial; text-decoration: none !important;">&nbsp; follow us on 
                                <span   style="text-decoration: none !important;">&#149 
                                <a style="color: #00b0ed; text-decoration: none !important;" href="https://twitter.com/SpectrumASA">twitter
                                </span></a>&#149
                                <a style="color: #3b5998; text-decoration: none !important;" href="https://www.facebook.com/spectrum.geo"> facebook
                            </a> &#149 <a style="color: #0077b5; text-decoration: none !important;"
                                href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/spectrum-asa">
                                     linkedin</a>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML from hotmail.com

```
<style>
.ExternalClass p.ecxMsoNormal, .ExternalClass li.ecxMsoNormal, .ExternalClass div.ecxMsoNormal {
font-size:11.0pt;
font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
}

.ExternalClass a:link, .ExternalClass span.ecxMsoHyperlink {
color:blue;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.ExternalClass span.ecxMsoHyperlinkFollowed {
color:purple;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.ExternalClass span.ecxEmailStyle17 {
font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
color:windowtext;
}

.ExternalClass .ecxMsoChpDefault {
font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
}

.ExternalClass div.ecxWordSection1 {
}

</style>


<div class="ecxWordSection1">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="ecxMsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
<table class="ecxMsoNormalTable" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<table class="ecxMsoNormalTable" style="width:100.0%;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<table class="ecxMsoNormalTable" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" nowrap="" valign="bottom">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style=""><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;
</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" nowrap="" valign="bottom">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal"><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#005A83;">Shamraiz Akhtar</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:17.25pt;">
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;height:17.25pt;" nowrap="" valign="bottom">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#92D050;">Technical Support Engineer</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" valign="bottom">
<table class="ecxMsoNormalTable" style="width:100.0%;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" valign="bottom">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal"><img src="https://dub111.afx.ms/att/GetInline.aspx?messageid=dbd438e5-cd89-11e4-94d4-d89d675c89ae&amp;attindex=0&amp;cp=-1&amp;attdepth=0&amp;imgsrc=cid%3aimage001.jpg%4001D06196.9A364160&amp;cid=8cdc5241b8bbef16&amp;hm__login=shorif2000&amp;hm__domain=hotmail.com&amp;ip=10.211.24.8&amp;d=d4389&amp;mf=32&amp;hm__ts=Wed%2c%2018%20Mar%202015%2016%3a14%3a46%20GMT&amp;st=shorif2000&amp;hm__ha=01_b23645d1fb986111e84fcc757dcb02baf2fd07545d47e67f35b5452c5bca60e4&amp;oneredir=1" alt="https://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg" align="right" width="168" height="46"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<table class="ecxMsoNormalTable" style="width:100.0%;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" nowrap="">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#92D050;">&nbsp; t:</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
</span><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#005A83;">+44 1483 730201</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" nowrap="">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="text-align:center;line-height:17.25pt;" align="center">
<span style="font-size:14.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">|
</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" nowrap="">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="text-align:center;line-height:17.25pt;" align="center">
<span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#92D050;">f:</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
</span><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#005A83;">+44 1483 762620</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="text-align:center;line-height:17.25pt;" align="center">
<span style="font-size:14.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">|
</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;"></td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;" nowrap="">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="text-align:right;line-height:17.25pt;" align="right"><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#92D050;">w:</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
</span><span style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#005A83;"><a href="https://www.spectrumgeo.com" target="_blank"><span style="color:#005A83;text-decoration:none;">spectrumgeo.com</span></a></span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<table class="ecxMsoNormalTable" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal" style="line-height:17.25pt;"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#005A83;">&nbsp; Dukes Court, Dukes Street, Woking, Surrey, GU21 5BH, UK</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<table class="ecxMsoNormalTable" border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm;">
<p class="ecxMsoNormal"><span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:#005A83;">&nbsp; follow us on •
<a href="https://twitter.com/SpectrumASA" target="_blank"><span style="color:#00B0ED;text-decoration:none;">twitter
</span></a>• <a href="https://www.facebook.com/spectrum.geo" target="_blank"><span style="color:#3B5998;text-decoration:none;">facebook
</span></a>• <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/spectrum-asa" target="_blank"><span style="color:#0077B5;text-decoration:none;">linkedin</span></a>
</span><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="ecxMsoNormal">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

If you follow the links on this there has not been any updates [Hotmail adding p tags within email, creating unwanted spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769851/hotmail-adding-p-tags-within-email-creating-unwanted-spacing) . The links are old so if there has been a solution since it would be great if someone can share their code.

Comment: can you post the problem HTML from outlook.com(hotmail)?

Comment: i have added the html code

Comment: well, that doesn't really help. I need to see the HTML after outlook has sent it, or the HTML outlook.com gets, from `<div id="bodyreadMessagePartBodyControl363f"...`

Comment: also, why did you wrap your styles in an HTML comment?

Comment: i have added the html from hotmail. i read it in quite a few places and saw examples with the quotes

Answer (score 0):

Outlook sends the `<p class="MsoNormal">` tags, and Outlook.com adds `ecx` to the class and the additional padding.

add `.ecxMsoNormal{padding:0; margin:0;}` to your `style` tag.

Comment: i have tried this already, i have read from google search results outlook strips out all html `style` tags and does not support `margin` ovverride i think.

Comment: both Outlook.com and Outlook (the application) support the `style` tag. Try sending the email to yourself in Outlook (the application) and see if the same thing happens. You also haven't said which version (2007, 2010, 2013, 365) of Outlook you're sending from.

Comment: I made a mistake in my wording i meant hotmail, sorry. question updated